# Get the newest file in any folder using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder which contains text and excel files. I want the newest or most newly modified excel file . I need to use that file name as an argument to some other program.

I am using below code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FILE="D:\IncrementalCompile\deploy\*.xlsx"
SET cmd="for /F %%i in ("%FILE%") do @echo %%~ni"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('%cmd%') do SET arg1=%%a
ECHO "%arg1%"
```

i am able to do this using Python. But my need is to use a batch program.
But this is not giving me the right result. Please help or suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
for /F %%i in ('dir D:\IncrementalCompile\deploy\*.xlsx /B /OD /A-D') do set arg1=%%i
ECHO "%arg1%"
```

Comment: Its showing error: "The system could not find the file specified."

Comment: @selbie,  you should add `"delims="` to the code as well otherwise file names with spaces will get split apart.

Comment: @priyabratamohanty, it is a lot easier to copy and paste the error message from the console window then taking a screen shot and linking to it.  Please do this going forward.

Comment: Below is the error:The system cannot find the path specified.
""
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0):

We are now in year 2018, and here is a powershell one-liner:

`dir *.xls | sort-object -property lastwritetime -descending | select-object -first 1`

Comment: What does the year have to do with anything?  I know people who still program in Fortran, Assembler and PL/1 because it is the best language for the tasks they need to accomplish.

Comment: But this does not work on cmd. Can i invoke the powershell into a batch script.

Comment: Of course you can. Even if script execution is disabled, it can be forced with some simple option.

Comment: @Squashman Exactly because the best language for task definition changes with time ;)

Comment: @ddbug : How can i able to  invoke the powershell into a batch script.

Comment: In the same way you invoke Python from batch script. Well I apologize for powershell, let's think we're back in 2002 with Windows XP...